# The PDF of $X$ is $\frac{1+\theta x}{2}$ for $x\in [-1,1], \theta \in[-1,1]$. Is the Method of Moments estimator of $\theta$ consistent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

We know that the method of moments estimator, $\hat{\theta}_n(\textbf{X})$, is consistent if

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|\hat{\theta}_n(\textbf{X})-\theta|>\epsilon)=0$$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}(X;\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1(x+\theta x^2) dx=\frac{\theta}{3}$, so $\hat{\theta}_n(\textbf{X})=3\bar{X}$.

Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|\hat{\theta}_n(\textbf{X})-\theta|>\epsilon)= \lim _{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|3\bar{X}-\theta|>\epsilon) $.

At this point I'm not sure how to proceed? I've tried using Chebyshev's inequality but this doesn't lead anywhere. I know that if a sequence in random variables converges in distribution to a constant then that is equivalent to  a sequence in random variables converging in probability to that constant. Now $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(\hat{\theta}_n(\textbf{X})\leq x)= \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(3\bar{X}\leq x)$ and I don't think this equals $\mathbb{P}(\theta\leq x)$? So would I be right in saying the method of moments estimator is not consistent?

Comment: How do you apply Chebyshev inequality here? If you do it right the problem should boil down to tommik’s reply.

Comment: @maths54321 : of course applying Chebishev's inequality the result doesn't change. See my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy use a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence in $L^2$ that is sufficient condition for consistency:

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\mathbb{E}[3\overline{X}_n]=3\cdot \frac{\theta}{3}=\theta$$

$$\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}]=\mathbb{V}[3\overline{X}_n]=\frac{9\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{3-\theta^2}{n}$$

Now being

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\theta$$

and

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}]=0$$

the estimator is consistent

---

Of course applying Chebishev's inequality the result is the same

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\Big\{\Big|3\overline{X}_n-\theta\Big|<\epsilon\Big\}\geq 1-\frac{3-\theta^2}{n \epsilon^2}=1$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'd just like to know exactly how you used Chebyshev's inequality here, I've only ever seen the form $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|< \epsilon)\geq 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$ with one r.v, $X$. I'm not sure how to derive the inequality with the sample mean involved?

Comment: @maths54321 : exaclty the one I applied. Just observe that $\sigma^2$ is the variance of your estimator that I calculated above. If my answer has been useful for you, you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Apologies again, maybe I've done this wrong, but when I compute the variance, I get $\text{var}(\hat{\theta})=\text{var}(3\bar{X})=\frac{9}{n^2}\text{var}(X_1+...+X_n)=\frac{9}{n}\text{var}(X)=\frac{9}{n}(\frac{1}{3}-\theta^2)$? I think $\text{var}(X)=\frac{1}{3}-\theta^2$? I'm not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: @maths54321 $E(X)=\theta/3$; $E(X^2)=1/3$ thus $V(X)=1/3-\theta^2/9$. You can accept my answer if it has been useful